# React App with Nginx reverse proxy not displaying /swagger ; /redoc

Tags: nginx, proxy

So I've been trying to set up Swagger to work on /swagger/, it was working fine until we switched to a domain. I'm not that experienced with nginx and it's reverse proxy. I will share my settings, if anyone could help. It actually opens the page, but it's all white, same goes with /redoc/ (Redis).

Nginx.conf

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
multi_accept       on;
}

http {

large_client_header_buffers 16 5120k;
fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
proxy_read_timeout 900;   
proxy_connect_timeout 900;
proxy_send_timeout 900;    

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;

proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
proxy_intercept_errors  on;

server {

    client_max_body_size 250M;
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {

    client_max_body_size 250M;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysite:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    }

    location /ht/ {
        proxy_pass http://mysite:8000/ht/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    }

    location /swagger/ {
        proxy_pass http://mysite:8000/swagger/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    }
```

For example, /ht/ (health check) is working just fine

urls.py in backend:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema- 
swagger-ui')]
```

Please tell me if you need any other files, I'm willing to share them, I just replace sensitive data with dummy data like mysite.com

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've just noticed that in Network tab, it shows for all CSS, JS files that "Javascript needs to be enabled to run this app", same goes for /redoc and also console log throws this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" for the JS files.

I've forgot to note it's a React App, but the App itself is working fine. Backend is in Python/Django
So I've been trying to set up Swagger to work on /swagger/, it was working fine until we switched to a domain. I'm not that experienced with nginx and it's reverse proxy. I will share my settings, if anyone could help. It actually opens the page, but it's all white, same goes with /redoc/ (Redis).

Nginx.conf

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
multi_accept       on;
}

http {

large_client_header_buffers 16 5120k;
fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
proxy_read_timeout 900;   
proxy_connect_timeout 900;
proxy_send_timeout 900;    

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;

proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
proxy_intercept_errors  on;

server {

    client_max_body_size 250M;
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {

    client_max_body_size 250M;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysite:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    }

    location /ht/ {
        proxy_pass http://mysite:8000/ht/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    }

    location /swagger/ {
        proxy_pass http://mysite:8000/swagger/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    }
```

For example, /ht/ (health check) is working just fine

urls.py in backend:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema- 
swagger-ui')]
```

Please tell me if you need any other files, I'm willing to share them, I just replace sensitive data with dummy data like mysite.com

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've just noticed that in Network tab, it shows for all CSS, JS files that "Javascript needs to be enabled to run this app", same goes for /redoc and also console log throws this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" for the JS files.

I've forgot to note it's a React App, but the App itself is working fine. Backend is in Python/Django